# Issue with body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, npm, body-parser

my console shows output as `undefined` even though tried with content type as application/json

app.js

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use('/posts', postRoute)
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

models

```
const PostSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Posts', PostSchema)
```

routes

```
router.post('/post', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body) //It displays undefined
})
```

Postman
[image]

Tried to include content type in headers but coudnt display the output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use the body parser before register other middlewares, else the body parser will set `req.body` after your middleware executes, which is why you see it as undefined

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/posts', postRoute)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest version of express, there is no more need for additional modules; you can just use the [build-in JSON module](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json).

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
  console.dir(req.body)
  res.send('echo')
})
```

Works for me.